# PLSQL: ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

Tags: oracle

Please check my inserting in oracle.

```
SQL> desc post;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- --------------------

 POST_BY                                   NOT NULL NUMBER(15)
 POST_NO                                   NOT NULL NUMBER(8)
 TEXT                                               VARCHAR2(500)
 LANTITUDE                                          NUMBER(3,4)
 LONGITUDE                                          NUMBER(3,4)
 NO_LIKE                                            NUMBER(6)
 POST_DATE                                          DATE

SQL>  INSERT INTO post
  2             values(
  3                     1,
  4                     1,
  5                     'Say somthing from user ',
  6                     1,
  7                     1,
  8                     0,
  9                     sysdate
 10             );
```

Result:

```
    1,*
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the error is actually being caused by the way you declared the `NUMBER` type for certain of your columns:

```
NUMBER(3,4)
```

This is defining a number with a precision of 3 significant figures, with 4 of them occurring after the decimal place and -1 of them occurring before the decimal place.  Read this last sentence again carefully until you see why it doesn't work for the value 1. (It would work OK if you tried to insert the value 0.002 though... up to four decimal places, and the first has to be zero.)

If you want to give 4 decimal places of precision to your latitude and longitude values, then use the following defintion:

```
NUMBER(7, 4)
```

This means 3 digits before the decimal places and 4 digits after the decimal place.

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming because you are using number(3,4) as its datatype.Number(3,4) means there are 3 significant digits and 4 digits after decimal.Change it.I think then it will work.